# Successful Push Notifications from javapns but not showing up on ios devices

Tags: java, ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm using javapns 2.2 to send push notifications and am getting successful responses from it but the notifications are not showing up on my iOS test phone.  I've created a unit test that uses this code from the wiki:

```
@Test
public void shouldSendATestMessageNotifyingDeviceThatNewMessageIsReady()
        throws RepositoryException {
    NotificationService nService = new NotificationService();
    nService.sendNotification("incoming message",
            "4854862ec7b58a939538f2e1262a48a7e8a3331c5f0e11feb11e1a79ff764649");
}

public void sendNotification(String message, String deviceId) {
    try {
        List<PushedNotification> notifications = Push.alert(message, certLocation, certPassword, false,
                deviceId);
        for (PushedNotification notification : notifications) {
            if (notification.isSuccessful()) {
                    /* Apple accepted the notification and should deliver it */  
                    System.out.println("Push notification sent successfully to: " +
                                                    notification.getDevice().getToken());
                    /* Still need to query the Feedback Service regularly */  
            } else {
                    String invalidToken = notification.getDevice().getToken();
                    /* Add code here to remove invalidToken from your database */  

                    /* Find out more about what the problem was */  
                    Exception theProblem = notification.getException();
                    theProblem.printStackTrace();

                    /* If the problem was an error-response packet returned by Apple, get it */  
                    ResponsePacket theErrorResponse = notification.getResponse();
                    if (theErrorResponse != null) {
                            System.out.println(theErrorResponse.getMessage());
                    }
            }
    }
    } catch (CommunicationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeystoreException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm using the production push SSL cert (p12) that I created in keychain.  I have an adhoc build on my iOS device and I pulled the device Id that I pass into this test from `NSLog` code in my iOS app for the device I'm using for testing so it is valid.

I swapped out my prod cert with the dev cert and got the invalid token error as I would expect to make sure it was finding the file.

Not sure what else to look at since javapns is telling me the pushed message was sent successfully.  Ideas?

Comment: I've found that if there is a formatting error in your actual JSON formatted push message, it may never be delivered. Double check the message payload is correct.

Comment: It helps if you read the javadoc.  The third parameter into the alert() method is a boolean that indicates if you're in production.  So, with the adhoc iOS build using the production cert you'll need to set to **true**